# Web app cannot write to a file on my server that seems to have the right permissions

Tags: apache-2.2, permissions, ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app on an Ubuntu server.  In my Apache config I have set the user and group to www-data.  I want my rails app to write to a file.  I have set the file permissions as follows:

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data    0 Jun  5 22:35 notify_list.txt
```

Seems like rails should be able to write because the permissions are correct.  But I keep getting permission denied.  What are possible causes of this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you running your Rails application under Apache via mod_rails/[passenger](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide.html)?

You may need to set the user that passenger runs the Rails application with "PassengerDefaultUser". Since you mention www-data, I'm assuming an ubuntu or debian server, so this would probably be a separate vhost file in /etc/apache2/sites-available. Add the line:

```
PassengerDefaultUser www-data
```

To the correct vhost file. If you don't know which file, run "`sudo apache2 -S`" to show the available vhosts in the configuration and pick the file that matches the hostname you access the Rails app.

Answer (score 1):

See if you can get it to create a new file (say in /tmp) and see 
what user/group it creates it with.

Answer (score 0):

First idea: Do you have write permissions for the directory?

Also, depending on the apache config, you might not have access to files outside the document tree, so if you app lives in /var/www/htdocs, you won't have access to files outside  this directory.

Comment: no write permissions for the dir.  didn't know i needed that.  and yes, it exists outside of the doc tree.  if i chmod the file to 666, all works...so im not sure either of those would be the problem

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for asking the obvious, but... are you running rails in Apache? Because if you are running rails in Mongrel or similar you need to make Mongrel run as www-data.

Answer (score 0):

Can happen that the file has the immutable attr set.

Answer (score 0):

run 'ps aux' in a terminal window to see what user your rails app is running as.

Answer (score 0):

Try it manually : become that user ( `sudo su - www-data` ) and try to create the file in the shell.